# Using JavaScript, How do I highlight a tag if the id is provided in URL

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<a href="#apple">apple</a>
<a href="#orange">orange</a>
```

What I'm looking to implement is, using pure js,

- Highlight **apple link** if (window.location.hash) = "#apple"
- Highlight **orange link** if (window.location.hash) = "#orange"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const loc = window.location.href;
console.log(loc);
//gets location

const values = loc.split('/');
const link = values[values.length-1];
//split on mark / to get last part of the location

const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
//get all links

//on click event for all links, removes active class if added before
for(var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function () {
[].forEach.call(links, function(el) {
    el.classList.remove("active");
});
    };   
};

// adds active class for clicked link or if current location.
links.forEach(links => {
    if (links.href.endsWith(link)) {
      links.classList.add("active")
    };
    links.addEventListener("click", () => 
      links.classList.add("active"))      
});
```

```css
.active{
text-decoration: none;
color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#apple">apple</a>
<a href="#orange">orange</a>
<a href="js">js</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, The highlighting a link is working but have a problem now,

- When you click on a link, the url changes but the link doesn't get highlighted. Only when you click or URL and press enter, the link highlights

Comment: Is probably because the javaScript is only loading once in the beginning when the page loads. Not sure how to get around this. Any hint/ help will be really cool.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think this thru, forgot its for events on same page, so I added on click event to fire it. I also needed to add event to remove all active classes on previously clicked links in order for it to able to switch class from link to link. @BibekRajK.C. In demo you can click on both links, it will switch color.

Comment: Very cool, Thanks alot. What I'm doing now is, using previous code to highlight the link on-load and using this to highlight links on click. Cheers.

Comment: @BibekRajK.C. When I was writing last edit I was bit in hurry, so code ended up a bit messy, I cleaned it now a bit, also added option for highlight on load or click. Code above should do all you need with no need for previous ones. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

To start off you need to grab the DOM elements using javascript. This can be done in multiple ways but for simplicity I will show using querySelector.

```
anchors = document.querySelector('a')
```

So the variable anchors will have an NodeList of the two anchors above. Lets make them into an array.

```
anchors_array = Array.prototype.slice.call(anchors)
```

Now let's loop through this array and do a logic check to see if the hash is equivalent to the href.

```
for(let i = 0; i < anchors_array.length; i++)
  if(anchors_array[i].href === window.location.hash)
    // highlight code here.
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the process, helped alot. Cheers